# how to replace one substring with another in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, substring

I want to replace an `NSString` substring with another substring in Objective C.

I know how to locate the substring I want to replace:

```
        NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:substringIWantToReplace];
        NSString *substring = [string substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(range)];
```

But when it comes to actually removing/replacing it, I'm a little confused.  Do I follow the C++ method at [Replace substring with another substring C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643512/replace-substring-with-another-substring-c)?  Or the C method at [how to replace substring in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659694/how-to-replace-substring-in-c)?  There's a related question at [Objective-C: Substring and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214193/objective-c-substring-and-replace), but the string in question is a URL, so I don't think I can use the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your answer is here [Replace occurrences of NSString - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492236/replace-occurences-of-nsstring-iphone):
`[response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"aaa" withString:@"bbb"];` defenetly works on any string and URL also.

If your concern about percent-notation of url and you want to be sure it will be replaced properly, you can firstly decode string, replace, and then encode:

```
// decode
NSString *path = [[@"path+with+spaces"
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
    stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// replace
path = [path stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"aaa" withString:@"bbb"]
// encode
path = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                               NULL,
                                               (CFStringRef)path,
                                               NULL,
                                               (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                               kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

Comment: Thank you!  I meant actually that the string in the other question was a URL, where my string isn't.  The answers in that question seem based on the fact that it's a URL.  But anyway your answer gave me what I needed--thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I check for a substring and replace/remove substrings from NSString:

```
if([titleName rangeOfString:@"&quot;"].location != NSNotFound) {
     titleName = [titleName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
}
```

Comment: Very helpful but the other answerer got here first so I had to give him credit--still, thanks so much.

Comment: No Problem, just wanted to show how easy it is to do this task with Objective-C's inbuilt methods.